# How to turn off snapping while tumbling (3d rotating) in sculpt mode?

Tags: snapping

When I 3d rotate around my model as Im sculpting (I do this with middle mouse button), it does this annoying thing where it snaps to front side and 3/4 angles... I searched the forums and manuals about turning this off but no luck. Help please.  Thank you.

Comment: What Blender version? In 2.79 and prior locking to preset view could be done while Alt was pressed (after pressing mouse button to rotate). If it isn't then you use custom shortcuts and something is conflicting there

Comment: I have v2.80.75. Holding alt makes it even worse...just tried that. :*(